# Max Grade_points for Repeated Course by Student

Tags: sql, oracle, peoplesoft

I am working on a student enrollment database project. Students enroll in courses and receive grades. Sometimes a student repeats a course and gets a better grade. I need to calculate the sum of grade_point and credit by using only the best grade. So for each student that repeats courses in different semester, I have to determine what the highest grade is. emplid represents the student, course_id identifies a course,credit is credits hr of course, Grade_point is the numeric value of the letter grade, and term represents the semester session.

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
emplid couse_id credit_hr grade_pt term    
  0001    6001       3        4      Fall15 
  0001    6002       3       3.5     Fall15
  0001    6003       3        2      Fall15
  0001    6004       4       2.5     Sp16
  0001    6002       3       3.0     Sp16 
total(requirrd)      13      12
```

Sample code from OP's comment:

```
SELECT a.emplid
      ,a.subject
      ,a.CATALOG_NBR
      ,a.strm
      ,a.CRSE_GRADE_OFF
      ,a.R‌​EPEAT_CANDIDATE
      ,a.un‌​t_taken AS cr
      ,a.CRSE_ID
      ,MAX(a.grade_points)
 OVER (PARTITION BY A.emplid ,crse_id) 
 FROM ps_CLASS_TBL_SE_VW a
 WHERE emplid LIKE '06381313011%'
```

Comment: OK.  What have you tried?

Comment: Quick question: Credit hours are a characteristic of a course, regardless of the student who took it and the semester in which it was taught. If this is correct (it is, I had a whole career in academia), why is it a column in THIS table, and not in a separate table with information about courses?

Comment: @mathguy you right i created view according to my requirment.

Comment: i have try this @OldProgrammer bt it does not exclude min grade row of same repeat course please need help i am stuck.
SELECT a.emplid,a.subject,a.CATALOG_NBR,a.strm,a.CRSE_GRADE_OFF,a.REPEAT_CANDIDATE,a.unt_taken AS cr,a.CRSE_ID,MAX(a.grade_points) OVER (PARTITION BY A.emplid ,crse_id)
FROM ps_CLASS_TBL_SE_VW a WHERE emplid LIKE '06381313011%'

Comment: PLease don't post code in a comment, Nobody can read that.  Edit the question,and post properly formatted code there.  Thanks

Comment: The sum of grade point (after you ignore the same course with a lower grade) doesn't make sense, why are you including it? The "total grade points" are calculated by multiplying the grade points for each course by the number of credit hours, and adding the results (these products), not by adding the grade points themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
select emplid, sum(credit_hr), sum(grade_pt)
from (
select emplid, course_id, credit_hr, grade_pt, term,
row_number() over(partition by emplid, course_id
order by grade_pt desc) rn
from your_table
)
where rn = 1
group by emplid
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do this.

The problem is complicated, because - it seems - you want to show ALL the input rows in the result set, but then the various aggregates should consider only some rows.

The first part is easy: the subquery orders the rows for each combination of `EMPLID` and `COURSE_ID` in decreasing order of grade received and assigns them a row number (within the group) based on that order.

The outer query does the aggregation. I use `GROUP BY ROLLUP`, which allows a lot of flexibility. When the "rollup" is in fact each row by itself I show the actual credit hours and grade points for that row, but in the aggregates I sum over something else: namely, over the credit hours (and the credit hours multiplied by grade points) when the row number is 1, and `NULL` otherwise (which is treated as if it didn't exist when computing `SUM()`).

I created a second employee, who got the same score twice for the same course (so I can check that my solution doesn't give wrong answers in a case like that). I simulate a separate table for credit hours for each course id, and the join needed to get that in the result. Also, I do not sum grade points, since that is not what's done with grade point calculations; rather, I use the correct calculation, where each grade point is multiplied by the course hours, and then these products (only for the highest grade for each course, separately for each `EMPLID`), are added together.

```
with
     grades ( emplid, course_id, grade_pt, term ) as (
       select '0001', '6001', 4  , 'Fall15' from dual union all
       select '0001', '6002', 3.5, 'Fall15' from dual union all
       select '0001', '6003', 2  , 'Fall15' from dual union all
       select '0001', '6004', 2.5, 'Sp16'   from dual union all
       select '0001', '6002', 3  , 'Sp16'   from dual union all
       select '0003', '6002', 3.5, 'Sp16'   from dual union all
       select '0003', '6003', 2.5, 'Fall16' from dual union all
       select '0003', '6003', 2.5, 'Sp15'   from dual
     ),
     credits ( course_id, credit_hr ) as (
       select '6001', 3 from dual union all
       select '6002', 3 from dual union all
       select '6003', 3 from dual union all
       select '6004', 4 from dual
     )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing purposes only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE.
select emplid, course_id,
       case when grouping(term) = 0 then credit_hr
            else sum(case when rn = 1 then credit_hr end) end as credit_hr,
       case when grouping(term) = 0 then grade_pt
            else sum(case when rn = 1 then credit_hr * grade_pt end)
                                                          end as total_grade_pt,
       term
from   ( select g.emplid, g.course_id, c.credit_hr, g.grade_pt, g.term,
                row_number() over (partition by g.emplid, g.course_id 
                                   order by g.grade_pt desc) as rn
         from   grades g join credits c on g.course_id = c.course_id
       )
group by rollup(emplid, course_id, credit_hr, grade_pt, term)
having grouping(term) = 0 or (grouping(course_id) = 1 and grouping(emplid) = 0)
;
```

**Output**:

```
EMPLID  COURSE_ID  CREDIT_HR  TOTAL_GRADE_PT  TERM
------  ---------  ---------  --------------  ------
0001    6001               3               4  Fall15
0001    6002               3               3  Sp16
0001    6002               3             3.5  Fall15
0001    6003               3               2  Fall15
0001    6004               4             2.5  Sp16
0001                      13            38.5
0003    6002               3             3.5  Sp16
0003    6003               3             2.5  Sp15
0003    6003               3             2.5  Fall16
0003                       6              18
```